# Issue Obtaining Authentication Configuration in react to .net 6 Behind Traefik

Tags: .net, traefik

I'm encountering an issue when trying to obtain the authentication configuration in my .NET 6 Core application that runs behind Traefik as a reverse proxy. I'm getting the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (keycloack-direction-auth.com:443)
 ...
```

The error seems to be related to obtaining the authentication token configuration and the server connections. My React application makes requests via Axios and has security headers configured.

I've verified the following:

The authentication URL (keycloack-direction-auth.com) is correct and accessible.
The server connection is up and accessible.
The authentication tokens (Bearer) are valid and properly formatted.
CORS configuration allows requests from my domain.
Security configuration in my .NET 6 Core application seems to be set up correctly.
However, I'm still receiving this error. Can anyone help me identify what might be causing the issue and how to resolve it? maybe the conection beetwen .net and keyclock with traefic i'm not sure

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!